# How to get row index number in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a list or data frame in R, and I would like to get the row index, how do I do that? That is, I would like to know how many rows a certain matrix consists of.

Comment: The question is still very unclearly phrased.

Comment: I think that's because it is two questions:  the second sentence is what @BenBolker answered `nrow(x)` (i.e. giving the *dimensions* of the data frame).  The first sentence is about getting row numbers, which Shane answered (and naught1 improved) `as.integer(rownames(x))`

Answer (score 107):

I'm interpreting your question to be about getting row numbers.

- You can try `as.numeric(rownames(df))` if you haven't set the rownames.  Otherwise use a sequence of `1:nrow(df)`.
- The `which()` function converts a TRUE/FALSE row index into row numbers.

Comment: This is what I do too, since DF row names, even if they are numeric, don't necessarily correspond to the row index: `row(cars[34:50,])[,1]; as.integer(rownames(cars[34:50,]))`. By why do you use `as.numeric()` here? Wouldn't it make more sense to use `as.integer()`?

Answer (score 17):

It not quite clear what exactly you are trying to do.

To reference a row in a data frame use `df[row,]`

To get the first position in a vector of something use `match(item,vector)`, where the vector could be one of the columns of your data frame, eg `df$cname` if the column name is cname.

Edit:

To combine these you would write:

`df[match(item,df$cname),]`

Note that the match gives you the first item in the list, so if you are not looking for a unique reference number, you may want to consider something else.

Comment: This is a good answer to a different question than I believe @lebesgue's alter ego is asking. If you type `head(df)` there are titles over all of the columns except for the row ID. So I think @lebesgue is looking for a function that will allow access to the row ID (the `row` function).

Answer (score 12):

See `row` in `?base::row`. This gives the row indices for any matrix-like object.

Answer (score 12):

```
rownames(dataframe)
```

This will give you the index of dataframe

Comment: But note that it will return the row index (which is really numeric), as a character vector, so you have to convert it back to numeric for many situations (for example plotting).

Comment: Yeah, I like this solution because it is simple, but maybe `as.numeric(rownames(dataframe))` would be better.

Answer (score 4):

If i understand your question, you just want to be able to access items in a data frame (or list) **by row**:

```
x = matrix( ceiling(9*runif(20)), nrow=5  )   
colnames(x) = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
df = data.frame(x)      # create a small data frame

df[1,]                  # get the first row
df[3,]                  # get the third row
df[nrow(df),]           # get the last row

lf = as.list(df)        

lf[[1]]                 # get first row
lf[[3]]                 # get third row
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this complementary example of "match" would be helpful.

Having two datasets:

```
first_dataset <- data.frame(name = c("John", "Luke", "Simon", "Gregory", "Mary"),
                            role = c("Audit", "HR", "Accountant", "Mechanic", "Engineer"))

second_dataset <- data.frame(name = c("Mary", "Gregory", "Luke", "Simon"))
```

If the name column contains only unique across collection values (across whole collection)
then you can access row in other dataset by value of index returned by match

```
name_mapping <- match(second_dataset$name, first_dataset$name)
```

match returns proper row indexes of names in first_dataset from given names from second:     `5 4 2 1`
example here - accesing roles from first dataset by row index (by given name value)

```
for(i in 1:length(name_mapping)) {
    role <- as.character(first_dataset$role[name_mapping[i]])   
    second_dataset$role[i] = role
}
```

===

```
second dataset with new column:
     name       role
1    Mary   Engineer
2 Gregory   Mechanic
3    Luke Supervisor
4   Simon Accountant
```

[r](/questions/tagged/r)

Answer (score 1):

```
x           <-  matrix(ceiling(9*runif(20)), nrow=5)
colnames(x) <-  c("these", "are", "the", "columnes")
df          <-  data.frame(x)
```

*Result:*
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3PEY.png)

```
which(df == "2") #returns rowIndexes results from the entire dataset, in this case it returns a list of 3 index numb
```

*Result:*

> 5 13 17

```
length(which(df == "2")) #count numb. of rows that matches a condition
```

*Result:*

> 3

You can also do this column wise, example of:

```
which(df$columnName == c("2", "7")) #you do the same with strings
length(which(df$columnName == c("2", "7")))
```