# Change Column into Index

Tags: r

I have a table like below and I am trying to convert it in such a way that first column becomes the index i.e. I can use bar-plot like functions on it.

```
               TFR_TT      ML            BGT  
1                0       26795        1577776.4
2                2        2779         432500.0
3                6           1            187.2
```

To Something like below

```
                        ML            BGT  
               0       26705         1577776.4
               2        2779          432500.0
               6           1             187.2
```

And then run the line chart so I can get 0,2,6 as Point between X axis as ML and Y Axis as BGT

Comment: what is your database? mysql? mssql?

Comment: Does it matter. Still it's a csv.

Comment: Assuming it's an R object called frame, you need only do `index(frame) <- frame$TFR_TT;frame <- frame[,-frame[,1]]`

Comment: How was I supposed to know it's a csv? i figured these were database columns. anyway, [check this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/gettng-the-row-number-based-on-column-conditions-td3041549.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370515/how-to-get-row-index-number-in-r) and [this](https://www.google.com)

Comment: @J-Dizzle the tag `r` should have told you that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the index, you have to set the rownames(). In the past, i've used a [as.table.data.frame()](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/86d3b55093124bd53281) helper function to just do

```
#sample data
dd<-structure(list(TFR_TT = c(0L, 2L, 6L), ML = c(26795L, 2779L, 
1L), BGT = c(1577776.4, 432500, 187.2)), .Names = c("TFR_TT", 
"ML", "BGT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"
))

barchart(as.table(dd, rownames=1)[,-1])
```

This takes care of reformatting the object and setting the names if you specify a `rownames=` parameter.

I'll include the source here for completeness

```
as.table.data.frame<-function(x, rownames=0) {
    numerics <- sapply(x,is.numeric)
    chars <- which(sapply(x,function(x) is.character(x) || is.factor(x)))
    names <- if(!is.null(rownames)) {
        if (length(rownames)==1) {
            if (rownames ==0) {
                 rownames(x)
            } else {
                as.character(x[,rownames])
            }
        } else {
            rownames
        }
    } else {
          if(length(chars)==1) {
            as.character(x[,chars])
        } else {
            rownames(x)
        }
    }
    x<-as.matrix(x[,numerics])
    rownames(x)<-names
    structure(x, class="table")
}
```

Comment: MrFlick. When I am running your code , it's giving me an error like "Error in as.table.default(dd, rownames = 1) : cannot coerce to a table" Also I have changed "barchart" to "barplot"

Comment: Did you use the sample data.frame I used above (`dd`)? How is your data.frame different than mine? What is the class() if your data? Is it already a table?

Comment: yes, completely copied and just changed barchart to barplot.

Comment: Did you get any errors when you copy/pasted the `as.table.data.frame` code?

Comment: Sorry, I did not copied the as.table properly. Its working now. Thanks. Is there an easier way to the same thing.

Comment: I tried to give you the easiest way possible. Most of that function deals with names. You can convert to matrix, then table, then add rownames if you want to do it yourself. It should be pretty easy to read what that function is doing.