# How to use the index of data as x-axis in R

Tags: r, plot, indexing, x-axis

How do I call the `index` of my `data.frame` in `R` like this

```r
x <- index(data) 

y1 <- data$y1

y2 <- data$y2
```

My `data.frame` have 3 variables. My `ID` variables does not have all unique values, as most of my individuals have two scenarios. While the `index` (provided by `R`) lists my data from `1:40` (40 values). I want my x-axis to go from 1 to 40.

```r
ID {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7, 12, ..., 50, 51, 57, 57}

y1 {....}

y2 {....}

plot(y1)
```

plots the `index` automatically as x-axis. I want to specify this manually.

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and share your data using `dput()`

Comment: Are you looking for `seq(nrow(data))`? Also `seq_along(y)` is another option.

Comment: Yeah I was looking for nrow. This question have been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2370770/4190720. x <- 1:nrow(df) was the solution for my problem. Thank you!